# Spring XML bean to configure two caffeine caches

Tags: java, xml, spring, caching

I am trying to setup caffeine cache using spring xml bean configuration. 
I want to have two different caches,

1. to store "id"
2. to store "name"

I tried doing following,

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager">

    <property name="cacheNames">
        <set>
            <value>id</value>
            <value>name</value>
        </set>
    </property>
    <property name="cacheSpecification" value="${caffeine.spec}"/>
</bean>
```

Code where I am using it looks like,

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = {"id"})
public String getId(final String key){
  System.out.println("no id in cache");
  //code
}

@Cacheable(cacheNames = {"name"})
public String getName(final String key){
  System.out.println("no name in cache");
  //code
}
```

The `getId()` method somehow works as per the `caffeine.spec` values which is `maximumSize=500,expireAfterAccess=5s` in my project. So if I call the method within 5 sec it does not print the message and if I call it within 5sec it calls the method. But the `getName` does not work. It prints the message all the time.
Anyone has ever tried to setup caffeine cache to setup multiple caches.

Just a note for people looking for an answer for above issue, Looks like the above configuration actually works, it must have been some other issue which did not work for me at that time.

Comment: Actually, I cannot reproduce your issue. I've created a demo project with Spring Boot and both caches works as a charm with your XML configuration. Are you sure you call the `getName()` method always with the same key parameter?

Comment: @DanielOlszewski That is interesting, somehow it did not work for me, so I moved on with adding a configuration bean and did it programmatic way. In addition to issue above I was also trying to configure different ttl for two different caches. I could not figure out how to do it using spring bean. Doing it in code was much easier.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue with cache configuration. Appeared that there was another cache provider in the class-path (Guava) which has been chosen by Spring instead of Caffeine.

You have to specify which cache provider is the default one by using
**spring.cache.type=caffeine** property. However you have solved this with configuration bean.

Hope that will save some time to other people.